on macOS, when a call is active and the microphone is in use, the API does not work with the Bluetooth headset
navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('play', () => {
    console.log('Play action received');
    // Add your play logic here
});

navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('pause', () => {
    console.log('Pause action received');
    // Add your pause logic here
});

navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('seekbackward', () => {
    console.log('Seek backward action received');
    // Add your seek backward logic here
});

I have integrated the Navigator Media Session API. It works fine on Windows and also on macOS. However, on macOS, when a call is active and the microphone is in use, the API does not work with the Bluetooth headset.
